# Realm : uncaught exception in notifier thread: N5realm10LogicErrorE: Bad version number

Tags: swift, realm, rx-cocoa

I have integrated realm in my project. I am working on swift 2.3 and when i am trying to run my project i am getting uncaught exception in below file and mentioned function and throws LogicError.

group_shared.hpp file

```
template <class O>
inline void SharedGroup::advance_read(O* observer, VersionID version_id)
{
  if (m_transact_stage != transact_Reading)
    throw LogicError(LogicError::wrong_transact_state);

  // It is an error if the new version precedes the currently bound one.
  if (version_id.version < m_read_lock.m_version)
    throw LogicError(LogicError::bad_version);

  _impl::History* hist = get_history(); // Throws
  if (!hist)
    throw LogicError(LogicError::no_history);

 do_advance_read(observer, version_id, *hist); // Throws
}
```

Comment: What version of Realm are you using? Can you please show the code around that you use Realm?

Comment: We're tracking this issue as bug on GitHub https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4422, but haven't been able yet to reproduce it ourselves. If you could provide us a sample project reproducing this issue (privately to help@realm.io), this would help a lot.

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue. joninsky has shared a sample project and Realm team is yet to respond. @marius

Comment: @KushalAshok let me know if you get any response from realm developers?

Comment: Good news here as you might already have seen from the issue. We've located the issue and have a fix for that in place and expect to ship this in the next releases.